# BeautifulSoup not finding all tags when using .find method?

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape from https://github.com/trending the number of of trending repositories using BeautifulSoup in Python. The code is supposed to find all tags with class_ = "Box-row" and then print the number found. On the site the actual number of trending repositories is 25 but the code only returns 9.

I have tried changing the parser from 'html.parser' to 'lxml' but both returned the same results.

```
page = requests.get('https://github.com/trending')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text)
repo = soup.find(class_ = "Box-row")
print(len(repo))
```

In the html there are 25  tags with "Box-row" class attributes so I expected to see print(len(repo)) = 25, but instead it's 9.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
repo = soup.find_all("article",{"class":"Box-row"})
```

Comment: I just realized, you can use your code too. just use `find_all` instead of `find`.

Comment: You've also an extra line of code that you might not need `soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text)`. Not sure if it's your typo or what.